# Se deshabilita script al empezar la escena - C# Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity2d

Llevo horas intentando solucionar el error, tengo un script el cual utilizo para pasar información entre escenas, como el personaje que seleccioné en la escena de selección de personajes que tengo creada. Todo esto funciona, pero el script se deshabilita al entrar en la escena, y tengo que activarlo manualmente cada vez que entro al juego, cosa que no podré hacer desde dispositivo móvil.

Aquí el script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class conservar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static conservar estado;
    private string rutaArchivo;
    public int per = 0;
    public int puntuacionMaxima = 0;
    public int lastpunt = 0;
    public Meters M;
    public int Mtrs = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        GameObject CharSel = GameObject.Find("/personaje/CHarSel");
        CharSel.GetComponent<CharSel>();
        GameObject DispChar = GameObject.Find("/DispChar");
        DispChar.GetComponent<DispChar>();

        rutaArchivo = Application.persistentDataPath + "/datos.dat";

        if (estado==null)
        {
            estado = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else if (estado != this)
        {
           Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Cargar();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        per = DispChar.perso;

        if (per == 0)
        {
            CharSel.Character = 0;
        }
        if (per == 1)
        {
            CharSel.Character = 1;
        }
        if (per == 2)
        {
            CharSel.Character = 2;
        }
        if (per == 3)
        {
            CharSel.Character = 3;
        }
        lastpunt = M.meters;
    }
    public void Guardar()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(rutaArchivo);

        DatosAGuardar datos = new DatosAGuardar();
        datos.puntuacionMaxima = puntuacionMaxima;

        bf.Serialize(file, datos);

        file.Close();
    }
    void Cargar()
    {
        if (File.Exists(rutaArchivo))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(rutaArchivo, FileMode.Open);

            DatosAGuardar datos = (DatosAGuardar)bf.Deserialize(file);
            puntuacionMaxima = datos.puntuacionMaxima;

            file.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            puntuacionMaxima = 0;
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    class DatosAGuardar
    {
        public int puntuacionMaxima;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta: Tras mas horas de búsqueda encontré el error:

```
GameObject CharSel = GameObject.Find("/personaje/CHarSel");
CharSel.GetComponent<CharSel>();
```

El objeto el cual buscaba en esta linea de código llamado CharSel, se situaba en otra escena, lo que no dejaba avanzar al script ya que se quedaba buscando este objeto infinitamente, suprimiendo esta linea de código y añadiendo una referencia al objeto, añadiendo al principio del código:

```
public GameObject CharSel;
```

y arrastrando desde el editor el prefab del objeto CharSel se soluciona el error.